# Where is the Log for Azure Service Bus Topic Subscriptions Messages Sent/Delivered?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

After searching in vain... where can I see a log/list of which Azure Service Bus Messages (content?) have been sent to a given Topic+Subscription and which ones have been delivered? Do I have to activate a special feature? If so, which? New or "classic" Azure Management Portal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in either portal to my knowledge. You can use something like Service Bus Explorer http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2015/03/02/service-bus-explorer-2-6-now-available.aspx to see delivered messages.

Comment: Thx. I am familiar with both. The SvcBus Explorer is nice, but is much more than a logging and tracing tool and is not intendet to monitor & log all types of sources and sinks as far as I can see. The Portal itself just has counters and general feedback. I currently use my own logging of a subscription endpoint to monitor each msg but it is very "low end". There must be more?

Comment: I am doing exactly the same. Used products like NServiceBus in the past (with MSMQ for transport, not ASB) - and logging + monitoring is an extra there as well, not part of the standard package.

Comment: Will add as answer if nobody has a beter idea :-)

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for journalling, which I don't believe is in ASB at the moment. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/8016018-journaling-for-topics-and-queues. Several people have built their own journalling workaround in ASB by having a subscriber on a topic listen for all messages, and log those messages within its own application space.