# Azure WebApps: Changes to Razor Views not being updated no matter what I delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, razor, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

I'm using the latest version of .Net 4.6 MVC 5, Visual Stidio 2015 and Azure AppServices/Websites and SDK.

I have verified in the WebDeploy Preview that my _PartialXYZ.cshtml view is slated for update and is indeed deployed.

I have even deleted the file from the Azure deployment via the VisualStudio 2015 server view, restarted the AppServices, and killed the browser cache on several different browsers and machines. Same result: the file _PartialXYZ.cshtml from a few days ago (without my changes) is loaded, even in debug/firebug mode in chrome and firefox.

This is highly unusual to say the least. Who can tell me what I am missing --

some etag settings, or killing IIS on my (non shared) AppService instance?

OK, I can still try to rebuild and redeploy my whole system, but this is getting rediculous. And no, I will not delete and redeploy my Azure AppService instance, since I'd lose all of my tens of Cloud AppSettings in the process...

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not sound right. Nothing is cached on the server after a site restart.

My best guess is that you are not hitting the right site. e.g. maybe your site has Slots, and you're deploying to the slot and hitting the production site?

Try using [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to make sure you are looking at the right site/files.

If that doesn't help, please share your site name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate.

Comment: Thanks David, indeed, does not sound right. Yes, but the slotname should be in the url name... I'll check and get back. By chance know anyone who can answer this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219521/where-is-the-log-for-azure-service-bus-topic-subscriptions-messages-sent-deliver

Comment: Kudu helped. Very nice tool. I was loading an old debug _Partial that I had not yet deleted. My bad. Sorry. Thanks for the tip.